How do I write a definition/theorem with an arbitrary number $n$ of types?
I am trying to use mathlib to write the definition of a monoidally well-pointed monoidal category. This definition goes like: For all parallel pairs of morphisms $f, g : A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n \to B$, we have $f = g$ when $f \circ \left(a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_n\right) = g \circ \left(a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_n\right)$ for all states $a_1 : I \to A_1, \ldots, a_n : I \to A_n$. How exactly would I write a definition like this? It's not hard to write of course for some definite $n$, but I feel like I'm missing something to be able to write it for an arbitrary $n$. I'm not exactly sure how to make "$\cdots$" precise. The MWE I'm working with looks like this:
import Mathlib.CategoryTheory.Products.Basic

open CategoryTheory

namespace Quantum

universe v₁ v₂ u₁ u₂

variable ( : Type u₁) [Category.{v₁} ]

class MonoidalCategoryData where
 tensorProduct :  ×  ⥤ 
 unitObject : 
 associator : ∀ A B C : , tensorProduct.obj ((tensorProduct.obj (A, B)), C) ≅ tensorProduct.obj (A, (tensorProduct.obj (B, C)))
 leftUnitor : ∀ A : , tensorProduct.obj (unitObject, A) ≅ A
 rightUnitor : ∀ A : , tensorProduct.obj (A, unitObject) ≅ A

scoped notation:70 lhs:71 "⊗" rhs:70 => MonoidalCategoryData.tensorProduct.obj (lhs, rhs)
scoped notation:70 lhs:71 "⊕" rhs:70 => MonoidalCategoryData.tensorProduct.map (lhs, rhs)
scoped notation "" => MonoidalCategoryData.unitObject
scoped notation "α" => MonoidalCategoryData.associator
scoped notation "γ" => MonoidalCategoryData.leftUnitor
scoped notation "ρ" => MonoidalCategoryData.rightUnitor

class MonoidalCategory extends MonoidalCategoryData  where
 triangle : ∀ A B : , (α A  B).hom ≫ (( A) ⊕ (γ B).hom) = ((ρ A).hom ⊕ ( B) : (A ⊗ ) ⊗ B ⟶ A ⊗ B)
 pentagon : ∀ A B C D : , ((α A B C).hom ⊕ ( D)) ≫ (α A (B ⊗ C) D).hom ≫ (( A) ⊕ (α B C D).hom) = (α (A ⊗ B) C D).hom ≫ (α A B (C ⊗ D)).hom

variable (ℳ : Type u₂) [Category.{v₂} ℳ] [MonoidalCategory ℳ]

class MonoidallyWellPointedMonoidalCategory extends MonoidalCategory ℳ where
 monoidallywellpointed : sorry

Thanks for your time.

I will have time to answer more properly later, but briefly, the idea is that you want to speak about lists of objects and lists of morphisms. (1) Define a tensor_list : List  →  that tensors a list of objects. (2) Note that List ((A : ) × (I ⟶ A)) is a list of pairs (A, f : I → A). Define a map tensor_homs which takes such a list and produces the morphisms I → A_1 ⊗ ⋯ ⊗ A_n. (3) Make statements of the form "forall fs : List ((A : ) × (I ⟶ A)) blah blahtensor_hom fs blah blah".

Using lists is a very good idea, thank you! I'll see if I can try to implement what you describe here myself now.

Note, since you are using mathlib, it already has a definition of MonodialCategory.  (Found with https://Moogle.ai.) Andre’s List comment is spot on, and also note it is canonical to associate repeated tensor products to the right (like type products).  You could use List.foldr to do that.

I'm aware of mathlib's MonoidalCategory. I'm starting with defining it myself for learning and exercise.
So far I think I've correctly characterized tensor_list with induction, with I for List.nil and A ⊗tensor_list As for List.cons A As, which is at least isomorphic to what I want. My current confusion is with figuring out tensor_homs. Primarily, there isn't a similar 'tensor identity' morphism to use for the base case. It's making me think there might be another way that I am not aware of.

You need to use specifically the fact that you're mapping out of $I$. Given $f : I \to A$ and $g : I \to B$ the functorial action of $\otimes$ gives $f \otimes g : I \otimes I \to A \otimes B$, and then you precomopse that with $I \otimes I \cong I$.

If I may also say, your condition involving $n$-fold tensoring seems strange. Isn't it equivalent to requiring just the cases $n = 0$ annd $n = 2$? That would allow you to skip lists altoghether.

Hm... By this do you mean that we can just write the definition for $n = 2$ because we just get an object of the correct types from the tensors anyways? So the definition monoidallyWellPointed : ∀ A₁ A₂ B : ℳ, ∀ f g : (A₁ ⊗ A₂) ⟶ B,∀ a₁ : State ℳ A₁, ∀ a₂ : State ℳ A₂, (a₁ ⊕ a₂) ≫ f = ((a₁ ⊕ a₂) : ( ⊗ ) ⟶ (A₁ ⊗ A₂)) ≫ g → f = g is sufficient? That does make sense to me. (State is def State (A : ℳ) :=  ⟶ A)

I do not know what "object of the correct type" means. What I am saying is that your condition for general $n$ follows already from $n = 2$ and $n = 0$ (which is trivial, I suppose).
